# Can you express 'valid for lifetime of returned value' in the lifetime system?

Tags: rust

This is an issue I've encountered several times.

- You have data that needs to go to a task.
- You want to safely send the data to the task and process it remotely.
- ...and you what to wait for the result.

Something like this playpen: http://is.gd/fnhRta

```
use std::thread::Thread;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Foo<'a> {
  fp: &'a u32
}

impl<'a> Foo<'a> {
  fn new(v:&'a u32) -> Foo<'a> {
    return Foo {
      fp: v
    };
  }
}

fn main() {
  let value = 100;
  let foo = Foo::new(&value);
  let guard = Thread::scoped(|| {
    println!("{:?}", foo);
  });

  // We know foo is valid in the remote thread, because guard is in the same 
  // scope of foo... but how do we express that using lifetimes?
  guard.join();
}
```

Is it possible to express this using lifetimes?

Something which would, in essence, only accept a Foo<'a> where <'a> is <= the lifetime of the current `{ ... }` block.

Comment: This PR may be related to what you are trying to achieve : https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/22319

Comment: FYI, the Rust style is 4-space indents.

Comment: @Shepmaster please; I don't use implicit return statements either; for the same reason; I disagree with the 'standard' style. Fine or not... I think we can all agree it's completely irrelevant to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code as you wrote it now works:

```
use std::thread;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Foo<'a> {
    fp: &'a u32
}

impl<'a> Foo<'a> {
    fn new(v: &'a u32) -> Foo<'a> {
        Foo { fp: v }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let value = 100;
    let foo = Foo::new(&value);
    let guard = thread::scoped(|| {
        println!("{:?}", foo);
    });

    // We know foo is valid in the remote thread, because guard is in the same 
    // scope of foo... but how do we express that using lifetimes?
    guard.join();
}
```

This is likely due to [RFC 458](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0458-send-improvements.md), which relaxes the restrictions on `Send` / `Sync`. Now, [`thread::scoped`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/thread/fn.scoped.html) returns a `JoinGuard` with the same lifetime as the closure.